# get list if contains non zero element

Tags: python, list

I have a list.

```
l1 = [0, 0, 2, 0]
l2 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want to print list if list contains non zero element in it.

Output:

If one one list passed, then only list with non zero element will get printed. In example above only l1 will get printed.

```
[0, 0, 2, 0]
```

I want to know how efficiently it can be done. Thanks !

Comment: `if any(l1): print(l1)` or `if any(l2): print(l2)`.

Comment: `for i in [l1, l2, one_more_l...]: if any(i): print(i)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `any` on your lists:

```
for lst in (l1, l2):
    if any(lst):
        print(lst)
```

You can also use `all`:

```
for lst in (l1, l2):
    if all(x != 0 for x in lst):
        print(lst)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
lists = [[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 2, 0]]
for l in lists:
    if set(l)=={0}:
        pass
    else:
        print l
```

Comment: Is this efficient though, compared with `if any(): print`?

Comment: This will not stop early as soon as it finds the first non-zero entry, as `any` would. Also, `set(l) == {0}` is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in function `any()`:

From Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

> *any(iterable)*
>   Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If
>   the iterable is empty, return False

Here's a code:

```
for l in [l1,l2, ..., ln]:
    if any(l):
        print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `any` to test if the list contains at least one non-Falsy/non-zero element.

Zero is falsy, in fact the only falsy number:

```
>>> bool(0)
False
```

So you can easily do:

```
for lst in (l1, l2):
   if any(lst):
      print(lst)
```

This would provide correct results as long as your lists contains only numericals and you're not willing to make an expcetion of non numericals.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the comments, but I'll post it as an answer:

```
for l in filter(any, (l1, l2)):
    print(l)
```

The combination of [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#any) makes it so the `print` only executes for lists with non-zero elements. `any` returns `False` as soon as the first non-zero (or truthy) value is encountered. For integers, `0` is the only `i` for which `bool(i)` is falsey.